# OnTouch not working in Live Wallpaper

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

Hi I am making a live wallpaper by the help of http://www.rbgrn.net/content/354-glsurfaceview-adapted-3d-live-wallpapers. Now I want to attach touch detection on home screen. That is, after setting the wallpaper user can touch wallpaper so that corresponding action can take place. My source code is given below. It's working fine on preview of wallpaper but not after setting the wallpaper.

```
class MyEngine extends GLEngine 
{
    MyRenderer renderer;
    AnimationController animationController;
    public MyEngine() 
    {
        super();
        renderer = new MyRenderer();
        setRenderer(renderer);
        setRenderMode(RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder)
    {
        super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
    {
         if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE ) 
         {                        
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Move", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();             
         }
         else
         if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
         {                         
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();             
         }           

        super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

got the answer !! 
Just added this.setTouchEventsEnabled(true); in MyEngine Constructor.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was looking the solutions since 3 hours.. ;P